# Closed form for $\int_0^1 \left\{ \frac{m}{x}\right\}^n\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation, improper-integrals

I am trying to find the closed form for the following integral:
$$\int_0^1 \left\{ \frac{m}{x}\right\}^n\,dx, \quad \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. This integral is a generalization of some of the fractional part integrals found in Ovidiu Furdui's book *Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals: Problems in Mathematical Analysis*.

**My attempt:**
$$I(m,n):= \int_0^1 \left\{ \frac{m}{x}\right\}^n\,dx, \quad \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

\begin{align*}
I(m,n)
&\stackrel{x \mapsto \frac{m}{x}}{=} m\int_m^\infty \frac{\{x\}^n}{x^2}\,dx\\
&= m\sum_{k = m}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} \frac{(x-k)^n}{x^2}\,dx\\
&= m\sum_{k = m}^\infty \sum_{\ell=0}^n (-1)^\ell \binom{n}{\ell} k^n\int_k^{k+1} \frac{x^{n - \ell}}{x^2}\,dx\\
&= m\sum_{k = m}^\infty\left[ \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}\left[ (-1)^\ell \binom{n}{\ell} k^n\int_k^{k+1} \frac{x^{n - \ell}}{x^2}\,dx\right] + (-1)^{n-1}n k^{n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\,dx + (-1)^n k^n\int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx\right]\\
&= m\sum_{k = m}^\infty\left[ \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}\left[ (-1)^\ell \binom{n}{\ell} k^n\frac{(k+1)^{n-\ell-1}-k^{n-\ell-1}}{n-\ell-1}\right] + (-1)^{n-1}n k^{n-1} \log\left(\frac{k+1}{k} \right) + (-1)^n \frac{k^{n-1}}{k+1}\right]\\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} m\sum_{k = m}^N \left[ \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}\left[ (-1)^\ell \binom{n}{\ell} k^n\frac{(k+1)^{n-\ell-1}-k^{n-\ell-1}}{n-\ell-1} \right] + (-1)^{n-1}n k^{n-1} \log\left(\frac{k+1}{k} \right) + (-1)^n \frac{k^{n-1}}{k+1}\right]\\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} m\left[ \sum_{\ell=0}^{n-2}\sum_{k = m}^N\left[ (-1)^\ell \binom{n}{\ell} k^n\frac{(k+1)^{n-\ell-1}-k^{n-\ell-1}}{n-\ell-1} \right] + (-1)^{n-1}n \sum_{k = m}^N \log\left[\left(\frac{k+1}{k} \right)^{k^{n-1}}\right] + (-1)^n \sum_{k = m}^N \frac{k^{n-1}}{k+1}\right].
\end{align*}

From here I began to struggle. I believe I I was able to make some good progress with the sum with the logarithm. To do so I defined something I will call the generalized hyperfactorials (I do not know if such a function exists in literature):
$$\mathrm{H}(k,n) := \prod_{j = 1}^n j^{j^k}.$$
We see that if $k = 0$, we get the regular factorial. If we let $k = 1$, we get the hyperfactorial. With this function, I believe I the partial sum with the logarithms has a closed form:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = m}^N \log\left[\left(\frac{k+1}{k} \right)^{k^{n-1}}\right]
&= \log\left[\prod_{k = m}^N\left(\frac{k+1}{k} \right)^{k^{n-1}}\right]\\
&= \log\left[\frac{(m+1)^{m^{n-1}} \times (m+2)^{(m+1)^{n-1}} \times \ldots \times N^{(N-1)^{n-1}} \times (N+1)^{N^{n-1}}}{m^{m^{n-1}} \times (m+1)^{(m+1)^{n-1}} \times (m+2)^{(m+2)^{n-1}} \times \ldots \times N^{N^{n-1}}}\right]\\
&= \log\left[\frac{(N+1)^{N^{n-1}}}{m^{m^{n-1}}} \left((m+1)^{m^{n-1} - (m+1)^{n-1}} \times (m+2)^{(m+1)^{n-1} - (m+2)^{n-1}} \times N^{(N - 1)^{n-1} - N^{n-1}}\right)\right]\\
&= \log\left[\frac{(N+1)^{N^{n-1}}}{m^{m^{n-1}}} \left((m+1)^{((m+1) - 1)^{n-1} - (m+1)^{n-1}} \times (m+2)^{((m+2) - 1)^{n-1} - (m+2)^{n-1}} \times N^{(N - 1)^{n-1} - N^{n-1}}\right)\right]\\
&= \log\left[\frac{(N+1)^{N^{n-1}}}{m^{m^{n-1}}} \left((m+1)^{\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} (-1)^p \binom{n-1}{p}(m+1)^{n - p -1}} \times (m+2)^{\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} (-1)^p \binom{n-1}{p}(m+2)^{n - p -1}} \times \ldots \times N^{\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} (-1)^p \binom{n-1}{p} N^{n - p -1}}\right)\right]\\
&= \log\left[\frac{(N+1)^{N^{n-1}}}{m^{m^{n-1}}} \prod_{p=1}^{n-1}\left((m+1)^{(m+1)^{n - p -1}} \times (m+2)^{(m+2)^{n - p -1}} \times \ldots \times N^{ N^{n - p -1}}\right)^{(-1)^p \binom{n-1}{p}}\right]\\
&= \log\left[\frac{(N+1)^{N^{n-1}}}{m^{m^{n-1}}} \prod_{p=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{\mathrm{H}(n -p-1,N)}{\mathrm{H}(n -p-1,m)}\right)^{(-1)^p \binom{n-1}{p}}\right].
\end{align*}

Hopefully I did not make any typos. I believe the integrals has a strong connection to the Bendersky-Adamchik constants. Here are some papers on the constants

[Some new quicker approximations of Glaisher–Kinkelin's and Bendersky–Adamchik's constants](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14001899)

[Closed-form calculation of infinite products of Glaisher-type related to Dirichlet series](https://d-nb.info/1169554156/34)

From these papers, we can use the limit definition of the Bendersky-Adamchik constants to derive Stirling-like asymptotic formulas for the generalized hyperfactorials, which I conjecture will be handy when evaluating the limit. I also believe that the other sums left to be simplified could be simplified via the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula or even Faulhaber's formula somewhere down the line. Possibly the Bernoulli numbers from the definition of the limit definition of the Bendersky-Adamchik constants interact with Bernoulli numbers from the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. Is it possible that I am approaching this integral the wrong way? If so, what would be the best way to tackle this integral?

Comment: Your use of the quantifiers here does not make sense; quantifiers are for quantifying over a proposition, and what you have there is a function. You want to write something like $I(m, n)$ for the value of the integral as a function of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I fixed it!

Comment: The hyperfactorials divided by some suitable growing function are related to the value of $\zeta'(-k)$ by means of analytic continuation. You can actually derive the formula by applying Euler-Maclaurin summation to $\log H(k, n)$, but the general form may be quite complicated.

Comment: Could you check if my results are OK ? I am unable to compute the original integrals. Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: May be, you could answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
I(m, n) & = m\sum\limits_{k = m}^\infty  {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{(x - k)^n }}{{x^2 }}{\rm d}x} }  = m\sum\limits_{k = m}^\infty  {\int_0^1 {\frac{{s^n }}{{(s + k)^2 }}{\rm d}s} } \\ & = m\int_0^1 {s^n \sum\limits_{k = m}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(s + k)^2 }}} {\rm d}s}  = m\int_0^1 {s^n \psi '(m + s){\rm d}s}, 
\end{align*}
where $\psi'$ is the derivative of the [digamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.i).

Integrating by parts $n+1$ times gives
$$
 I(m, n) = ( - 1)^n n!m\left[ {\psi ^{( - n)} (m + 1) - \psi ^{( - n)} (m)} \right] + m\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {( - 1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - k)!}}\psi ^{( - k)} (m + 1)} 
$$
where $\psi^{(-k)}$ is a [polygamma function of negative order](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(98)00192-7). Their values may be expressed in terms of Bernoulli polynomials, harmonic numbers, derivatives of the Riemann zeta function and the Hurwitz zeta function, see Proposition $2$ in the above linked paper.

Alternatively, integration by parts once yields
$$ I(m, n) = m\psi (m + 1) - nm\int_0^1 {s^{n - 1} \psi (m + s){\rm d}s} 
$$
where $\psi$ is the digamma function. Then
$$
I(m, 1)  = m\psi (m + 1) - nm\log m,
$$
and, using the binomial series,
$$
 I(m, n) = m\psi (m + 1) + n\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\binom{n-1}{k}( - m)^{n - k} \left[ {\int_0^{m + 1} {s^k \psi (s){\rm d}s}  - \int_0^m {s^k \psi (s){\rm d}s} } \right]} 
$$
for $n\ge 2$. The integrals may be expressed again in terms of Bernoulli polynomials, harmonic numbers, derivatives of the Riemann zeta function and the Hurwitz zeta function, see Proposition $3$ in the above linked paper. The result should be identical to that arising from the first approach.

Comment: Do you think if the question were to be generalized to $$\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{m}{x} \right\}^n \log^\ell(x)\,dx$$ of $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\ell \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$?

Comment: I am not sure. Looks much more involved.

Answer (score 4):

*This does not answer the question.*

If
$$\Omega_{m,n}=\int_0^1 \left\{ \frac{m}{x}\right\}^n\,dx=m\int_m^\infty \frac{\left\{ x\right\}^n }{x^2}\,dx=m\sum_{k = m}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} \frac{(x-k)^n}{x^2}\,dx$$ then
$$\color{blue}{\Omega_{m,n}=\frac m {n+1}\sum_{k = m}^\infty \frac 1{k^2}\, \,\,_2F_1\left(2,n+1;n+2;-\frac{1}{k}\right)}$$ which are explicit for given $(m,n)$.

The problem (at least for me) is that arrive pretty quickly the derivatives of $\zeta$ function with negative arguments.

I give you below some expressions for $m=3$ before these derivatives appear.

They write
$$\Omega_{3,n}=-3 \gamma+a_n \log(\pi)- b_n\log (A)+(-1)^n\,3n\times 2^{n-1}\,\log(3)+R_n$$ where

- $a_1=0\qquad \qquad  \qquad\text{and} \qquad a_n=\frac 32 n \quad \forall n \ge 2$
- $b_1=b_2=0\qquad \qquad \text{and} \qquad b_n=3n(n-1) \quad \forall n \ge 3$

The unidentified terms $R_n$ are givn below.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & R_n \\
 1 & \frac{11}{2}  \\
 2 & -\frac{25}{2}-3\log(2)\\
 3 & 19+ \frac{63 }{2}\log (2) \\
4 &-\frac{97}{2}-78 \log (2)+\frac{9 }{\pi ^2}\zeta (3)\\
5 & \frac{323}{3}+\frac{465 }{2}\log (2)+\frac{45 }{2 \pi ^2}\zeta (3)+60 \color{red}{\zeta '(-3)} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Could you elaborate, please ? Finding the first patterns has been very tedious and I gave up. Why don't you put an answer ? Thanks & cheers :-)